# Scheduled Batch Apex Sequentially Error

Tags: apex, schedulebatch

I have 2 batch Apex classes that I am trying to run sequentially. I updated my classes based on a post I saw using a custom setting (BatchSchedule) with 1 field (Scheduled_Id__c) that is et to 0. However, I am getting an error message on the 1st class in the sequence when the batched run:

```
Failed to process batch for class 'AccountTotalEncountersBatch' for job id '7071C0000BcIUR8'

caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []

Class.AccountTotalEncountersBatch.finish: line 36, column 1
```

Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue?

**1st Batch Class:**

```
public class AccountTotalEncountersBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Account]);
    }
    public void execute(Database.batchableContext context, Account[] scope) {
        Map<Id, AggregateResult> results = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
            SELECT Account__c Id, COUNT(Id) amt 
            FROM Encounters__c 
            WHERE Account__c = :scope AND Age__c<366 GROUP BY Account__c]);
            
        for(Account record: scope) {
            AggregateResult amount = results.get(record.Id);
            if(amount != null) {
                record.Encounters__c = (Decimal)amount.get('amt');
            } else {
                record.Encounters__c = null;
            }
        }
        update scope;
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        BatchSchedule__c b = BatchSchedule__c.getOrgDefaults();
            DateTime n = datetime.now().addMinutes(2);
            String cron = '';

            cron += n.second();
            cron += ' ' + n.minute();
            cron += ' ' + n.hour();
            cron += ' ' + n.day();
            cron += ' ' + n.month();
            cron += ' ' + '?';
            cron += ' ' + n.year();

            b.Scheduled_Id__c = System.schedule('Batch 2', cron, new AccountTotalReferralsSchedule());

        update b;
    }         
}
```

**1st Batch Class Scheduler:**

```
global class AccountTotalEncountersSchedule implements Schedulable{
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc){
        AccountTotalEncountersBatch ref = new AccountTotalEncountersBatch();
        database.executebatch(ref,200);
    }
}
```

**2nd Batch Class:**

```
public class AccountTotalReferralsBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Account]);
    }
    public void execute(Database.batchableContext context, Account[] scope) {
        Map<Id, AggregateResult> results = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
            SELECT Account__c Id, COUNT(Id) amt 
            FROM Referral__c 
            WHERE Account__c = :scope AND Age__c<366 GROUP BY Account__c]);
            
        for(Account record: scope) {
            AggregateResult amount = results.get(record.Id);
            if(amount != null) {
                record.Referrals__c = (Decimal)amount.get('amt');
            } else {
                record.Referrals__c = null;
            }
        }
        update scope;
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        BatchSchedule__c b = BatchSchedule__c.getOrgDefaults();
            System.abortJob(b.Scheduled_Id__c);
    }         
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. You are calling `getOrgDefaults()` and then later `update` against the result. But if the default hasn't yet been inserted you get this error. To fix, simply change `update` to `upsert`.
2. Just use the `scheduleBatch` method instead, which is much simpler than managing cron expressions.

Updated Code:

```
public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context)
{
    BatchSchedule__c config = BatchSchedule__c.getOrgDefaults();
    b.Schheduled_Id__c system.scheduleBatch(new Batch2(), 'unique name', 2);
    upsert config;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I made those changes but now get a different error on my other batch. I'll put in a different post.